# Xamarin Forms generates wrong ressources

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android application with Xamarin Forms. After the update from Xamarin Forms 3.4.0.1029999 I have entries in my Resource.Designer like this:

```
        // aapt resource value: 0x7F030220
        public const int bottomtab.navarea = 2130903584;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7F030221
        public const int bottomtab.tabbar = 2130903585;
```

With these I get a lot of errors like this:

[image]

I assume that this is because of the point. Funny enough the build is successful nonethless.
How can I solve this errors?

Edit: the Link to the project: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox

Comment: Must be the old bin and obj folders causing their usual ruckus, did you try getting rid of them and clean building?

Comment: shoot, I thought I have already done that, but you are right. I deleted the bin and obj and that solved it.

Comment: Well shall i add an answer then?

Comment: that would be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: well, I just migrated back. I noticed that the new version seems to have an issue with the android linker so I thought It might be reasonable to wait a bit longer ^^

Comment: Want me to add that as an answer?

Comment: I think that is more of a work around than a real solution for that problem.

Comment: Well i have been using the same config on my app for more than a month and never saw this issue again so this issue seems to be unique too!!!

Comment: Didn't you say all your projects are currently on version 3.4.1029999? Since the error in my case also just occurs once I Upgrade to a higher version.

Comment: Literally 3 of them on the exact version mentioned above, working fine as hell!

Comment: So then it would be interessting to see what the difference is that your project work fine with 3.5.x and in mine are these errors during desing time. Nonethless I think downgrading is a workaround and not a real solution.

Comment: Sure, did you try the latest release though? 3.6 something?

Comment: yes, as we discussed before the latest version I tried was 3.6.0.264807. I also noted that with that version my Android crashed when I had the linker to set anything other that "None"

Comment: I tried looking around in GitHub as well could not find your bug like this!!

Comment: Want me to add this as an answer bro?

Comment: Good point, this should be an answer not a comment. I posted it as such.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if I added it?

Comment: Why would have that be better?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't have to add an extra answer! Anyway

Comment: I appreciate your effort and willingness to help. But I really still can't see why it would have been better if you would have added my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that was introduced recently with a change to the BottomTabLayout.axml file, ultimately causing the generated design file to use `.` characters instead of `_` characters. More details here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3007#issuecomment-486622711

The Xamarin engineers are aware of the problem and have a fix lined up that should be released soon, but in the meantime, you can fix this problem by falling back to the old `aapt` generator by following these steps:

1. Right-click on the Android project and select `Unload Project`. If the project disappears from the IDE, make sure that the solution is showing all files and not just files in the project.
2. Right-click on the unloaded Android project and select `Edit Project` to open the .csproj file.
3. In the first `PropertyGroup` tag, add in the following:

```
<AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>
    False
</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>
```

4. Save the changes, then right-click on the Android project and select `Reload Project`.

If all goes well, the errors should correct themselves now. You may have to clean and build, but in my experience, the correction was immediate once the Android project was reloaded. Note that according to the bug report, the `aapt` generator will be slower, which might be noticeable if changes are made to `axml` files and the Design Time Build is running.

Comment: This worked for me !!! After this I was getting few more compilation errors related route and routehost, But was able to resolve those after referring to the release note. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.0/4.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps every time you update Xamarin Forms

- Delete bin and obj as it has data of previous versions
- restart vs
- Clean build and run

Comment: Unfortunately this solves it only temporarily. After the next generation of the Resources.Designer file the issue is back.

Comment: Did you try to repeat the procedure or try updating to XF 3.6?

Comment: Yeah, multiple times on multiple PC's. Always the same result.

Comment: Did you try deleting the auto generated file and then build the android project again so it regenerated the resources!?

Comment: Yes I did. The interessting thing is that VS is generating the Resources.Designer again on every start in the obj - debug - designtime folder. and that is the file leading to the issue.

Comment: I am talking about the `ResourceDesigner.cs` file under the resource folder in android just so you know

Comment: Yeah, I deleted that one aswell. But it generates the other without having that around. Since it's only for designtime that might be the reason why the build is successful nonetheless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190602/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-npadrutt).

Comment: The only one that works. _obs delete droid bin/obj folders not portable/shared_