# Xamarin.Droid Resource.designer.cs is generated in a strange way?

Tags: xamarin.android

My Resource.Designer.cs file is always generated with a bunch of errors. I can compile and run the app just fine, even with the errors but it spams the Error List window.

In my case, the Resource.Designer.cs file contains these entries:

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7F020238
public const int bottomtab.navarea = 2130838072;

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020239
public const int bottomtab.tabbar = 2130838073;

...

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020240
public const int flyoutcontent.appbar = 2130838080;

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020241
public const int flyoutcontent.recycler = 2130838081;

...

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020242
public const int main.appbar = 2130838082;

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020245
public const int main.scrollview = 2130838085;

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020244
public const int main.tablayout = 2130838084;

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020243
public const int main.toolbar = 2130838083;

...

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020246
public const int shellcontent.appbar = 2130838086;

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020248
public const int shellcontent.scrollview = 2130838088;

// aapt resource value: 0x7F020247
public const int shellcontent.toolbar = 2130838087;
```

I already updated any NuGet package to the latest available stable version and I tried to re-generate this file. But it always comes up with these strange variable names ("." inside them) and generated entries within the Error List. So whats the proper way to solve this?

Comment: What errors do you get? Or you could share your demo. I notice in my `Resource.designer.cs`, variable names connect by "_" such as `Toolbar_subtitle`

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT well of course I get errors like "Syntax error", "A const field requires a value" and "; expected" multiple times. But it compiles and runs fine. And "Toolbar_subtitle" is also generated with "_" on my project. Just the ones above are strange... And I don't even know where they come from...

Comment: Firstly, we should remove the VS compile issue, deleting your `bin` and `obj` folders in your project(xxx, xxx.android,xxx.IOS), then rebuild your project.Then, if this issue is still existed, we should exclude the third-part libraries issue, you can remove the libraries one by one, and check the variable names in Resource.Designer.cs.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT after a bit more research I can confirm it is not a bug in my project because it affects others too. I already tried deleting `bin` and `obj`... this is a common "fix" for such problems. Take a look: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/461522/new-android-project-in-vs2019-preview-errors-on-pu.html so I think I can not do much about it until Xamarin fixes this crap... so maybe a fix in 5-6 years if I consider the fixing time of their other issues...

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297839/4067683. I hope that it solves the problem.

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/55138437/1726832