# Xamarin designer creating invalid Resource.designer.cs code

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am winding up with code like this in my Resource.designer.cs

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7F010213
public const int bottomtab.navarea = 2130772499;
```

Which is of course invalid because C# identifiers can't contain periods. The app runs just fine but I have 60 of these errors cluttering up the error list, burying any real errors I might have. How do I tell Xamarin to use legitimate names for its variables in Resource.designer.cs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms generates wrong ressources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137449/xamarin-forms-generates-wrong-ressources)

Comment: You could find this with the simple web search or search on the site. -1.

Comment: You can try clean project and rebuild it. And check whether used resource ID not exist in designer.